# JIRA API create issue and subtask in a single api call

Tags: javascript, jira, jira-rest-api

I am working on creating a script where I want to create a jira ticket along with several sub tasks. I am able to figure out creation of issue as well as sub tasks in different API calls with the following payload:

```
{
    "fields": {
       "project":
       { 
          "key": "TEST"
       },
       "summary": "TEST summary",
       "description": "TEST Description",
       "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
       }
   }
}
```

Create a sub-task and attach it to the issue from above API call:

```
{
    "fields":
    {
        "project":
        {
            "key": "TEST"
        },
        "parent":
        {
            "key": "TEST-1"
        },
        "summary": "Sub-task of TEST-1",
        "description": "TEST-1 desc",
        "issuetype":
        {
            "id": "5"
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to do both in a single API call. Is it something that can be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jira REST API does not offer such kind of operation. It does offer a `bulk` endpoint for creating multiple issues, but you can't define something like "issue one is the parent issue of issue two which is declared further down in the JSON file".

You have to use two different API calls:

1. Create your parent issue by using [`POST /rest/api/2/issue`](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.13.1/#api/2/issue-createIssue) and save the issue key from the response.
2. Create the sub tasks with a bulk operation using [`POST /rest/api/2/issue/bulk`](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.13.1/#api/2/issue-createIssues).

The links are referring to the REST API docs for Jira Server, but the same is possible with the [REST API in Jira Cloud](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-api-3-issue-bulk-post). Only the authentication method is different.

Comment: is this still not possible with the latest version?